# Eclipse: File matching strategy being called on single click of any view

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp

I wrote my custom File matching strategy by implementing IEditorMatchingStrategy as follows:

```java
public class FileMatchingStrategy implements IEditorMatchingStrategy {

@Override
public boolean matches(IEditorReference editorRef, IEditorInput input) {
    if (!(input instanceof IFileEditorInput))
        return false;
    if (null == input || null == editorRef) {
        return false;
    }

    IFile file = input.getAdapter(IFile.class);
    IPath rawFilePath = file == null ? null : file.getRawLocation();
    if (null == rawFilePath) {
        return false;
    }
    if("File.java".equals(rawFilePath.toOSString())){
        MessageDialog.openError(Display.getDefault().getActiveShell(),
            "Header", "Message");
        return true;
    }

    return false;
} }
```

Now whenever any of the view (for e.g. problems view) is clicked, the file matching strategy is being called which causes the popup to show even if file is not opened by double click.

Is it possible to filter out single clicks and handle only double clicks/Open File from project explorer?

Comment: No, there is no way to do that.

Comment: Thanks @greg-449.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there is no way to do that.

The `IEditorMatchingStrategy` is called whenever the `IWorkbenchPage` `openEditor` or `findEditor` methods are trying to find an editor matching the given editor input. There is no way stop this for particular calls.

The primary use of `IEditorMatchingStrategy` is for editors which support editing multiple files at once (such as the PDE plugin.xml/MANIFEST.MF/build.properties editor).

Eclipse does not expect `IEditorMatchingStrategy` to do any UI interactions.